# How do I do a UNION ALL that excludes all lines of data where an ID isn't common across both tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `UNION ALL` between 2 tables with multiple columns. There is a unique `ID` and multiple lines from both tables for the same `ID`.

What I want to do is exclude all the lines of an `ID` from table 1 if that `ID` cannot be found in table 2.

Below is a very simplified example of my query but effectively if `a.id` has lines of lets say 12345
but `b.id` doesn't then I want all those lines of 12345 excluding

```
SELECT a.id
       ,a.1
       ,a.2
       ,a.3
FROM table1 a

UNION ALL

SELECT b.id
       ,b.1
       ,b.2
       ,b.3
FROM table2 b
```

Comment: Put another way you want 2 rows there exists in table 1 AND 2 and 1 row if exists in 2 only.

Comment: btw title AND question aren't in synch

Answer (score 0):

I think a straightforward solution would be to use a sub-select in your first UNION, like so:

```
SELECT a.id
       ,a.1
       ,a.2
       ,a.3
FROM table1 a
where a.id in (select id from table2)

UNION ALL

SELECT b.id
       ,b.1
       ,b.2
       ,b.3
FROM table2 b
```